# Condition of complex roots on a quartic equation

Tags: polynomials

I have a quartic equation: $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$. 
How do I find its condition of the existence of complex root for $x$? (i.e. there is imaginary part of $x$)Is there any derivation available? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you are on a particular quartic there are methods like identifying the turning points and local extrema, or Sturm's theorem - which essentially solves the problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) - these methods can be turned into formulae, but it can be as easy to pursue the method.

Answer (score 2):

This is borrowed from Wikipedia article [Quartic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function).

> For a quartic equation $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$ with all coefficients real and $a\not=0$, we define the discriminant $\Delta$ as
>
> $$\Delta:=256a^3e^3-192a^2bde^2-128a^2c^2e^2+144a^2cd^2e-27a^2d^4+144ab^2ce^2-6ab^2d^2e-80abc^2de+18abcd^3+16ac^4e-4ac^3d^2-27b^4e^2+18b^3cde-4b^3d^3-4b^2c^3e+b^2c^2d^2$$
>
> and define the following polynomials
>
> $$P:=8ac-3b^2$$
>
> $$R:=b^3+8da^2-4abc$$
>
> $$\Delta_0:=c^2-3bd+12ae$$
>
> $$D:=64a^3e-16a^2c^2+16ab^2c-16a^2bd-3b^4$$
>
> Now, we can determine if the roots are real or not:
>
> - If $\Delta<0$ then the equation has two real roots, and two non-real roots which are provably complex conjugates.
> - If $\Delta>0$ then the roots are distinct and are either all real or all non-real:
>
>   - If $P<0$ and $D<0$ then all roots are real.
>   - If $P>0$ or $D>0$ then the roots are two pairs of complex conjugate non-real numbers.
>   - If $\Delta=0$ then there is at least one multiple root.
>   - If $P<0$, $D<0$ and $\Delta_0\not=0$ then there is a real double root and two distinct real roots.
>   - If $D>0$ or both of the following are true (1) $P>0$ and (2) either $D\not=0$ or $R\not=0$, then there is a real double root and two non-real complex conjugate roots.
>   - If $\Delta_0=0$ and $D\not=0$ there is a real triple root and a real simple root.
>   - Finally, if $D=0$, then
>
>     - If $P<0$ there are two real double roots.
>     - If $P>0$ and $R=0$ there are two complex conjugate double roots.
>     - If $\Delta_0=0$ then there is a real quadruple root, namely $x=-b/4a$.
>   - The cases left out here are not possible.

Comment: This is just a copy of part of a Wikipedia article. You should post a link to that article insted (as a comment).

Comment: Can anyone help me with the proof? Without derivation, I found it hard to understand. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos I wanted to do that, but unfortunately, I lack enough reputation for posting a comment. So, I decided to just copy everything in that article here, and that's also for my own future reference, because formulas in the Wikipedia cannot be copied.

Comment: @phiost https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.2373.pdf